# What is the meaning of the following reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

[Here.](https://redux.js.org/basics/example)

I am trying to understand what is the meaning of the following section in the reducer:

```
[
  ...state,
  {
    id: action.id,
    text: action.text,
    completed: false
  }
]
```

1) what is the meaning of ...state ?

2) Is the object following state, appended to state ?

Comment: It's called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) and it takes all the elements in the `state` array plus the new object and places them in a new array.

Comment: It means that you are adding another `object` to the array of the  state

Comment: Instead of asking what, try asking WHY it is done that way.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) what is the meaning of ...state ?

It's [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the existing `state` array into the new one.

> 2) Is the object following state, appended to state ?

yes, just like you would when creating a normal array literal `[{}, {}]`